# To show many notifications on the status bar

Tags: android, notifications

In my program, just one notification shown. I want to show many notifications in the status bar. Here is my code.

```
     NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();         // notification time
        Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "reminder", when);
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
        notification.flags |= notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, Goo.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent , 0);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(), "It's about time", "You should open the app now", contentIntent);
        nm.notify(NOTIF_ID, notification);
```

Comment: In this line  nm.notify(NOTIF_ID, notification); change NOTIF_ID every time you call this code ...

Comment: You want to say change like as NOTIF_ID=1;NOTIF_ID=2;NOTIF_ID=3;NOTIF_ID=4;

Comment: @Halo Yup and You have to change the Notification ID

Comment: @Halo:yes and call this code multiple time